# Having difficulty with using XmlTextReader to print out certain values inside certain elements to the command line from an external .xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmltextreader

I'm trying to store and print the value between `<name></name>` tags of, atleast, the first `<item></item>` element, but I can't "find", or "get to", the value of `<name></name>`.

(*please explain your scenario more clearly...*)

I plan on taking the extracted `name` value and converting it(all lowercase and add underscore for spaces between words) so that I can use it to search for an image file name within "images" folder.

If match is found - grab the file path to the image file, store it inside a variable and then create `<image></image>` within the current `<item></item>` element and paste the file path between the tags. Repeat that for another 999 items. If some of the items' `name` doesn't match any image file names - then create a log text file and store the names of the items that didn't get the match.

**XML structure**:

```
<items>
 <item>
  <name>Name1</name>
  <price>Price1</price>
  <description>Description1</description>
 </item>
 <item>
  <name>Name2</name>
  <price>Price2</price>
  <description>Description2</description>
 </item>
</items>
```

**Code**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;


    namespace myXmlParser
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\items_data.xml");
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                            reader.MoveToElement();
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
                            break;
                        //case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        //    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                        //    break;
                        //case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        //    Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        //    Console.WriteLine(">");
                        //    break;
                    }

                }
                Console.ReadKey();

            }// main
        }// class
    }// namespace
```

Comment: Sounds like you could find all the names using XPath > "/items/item/name".  Example:  http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/006271ec-4a28-46db-8fd8-6633cd1428b1

Comment: Among other things, you should not be using `new XmlTextWriter()`. That has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead. Also, your reader needs to be in a `using` block: `using (var reader = XmlReader.Create()){ /* code */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`reader.ReadContentAsString` when `reader.Name == "name"`.  
Since you plan on editing the XML later, you might as well use XmlDocument, and apply the XPath you were suggested earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Linq2Xml is easier to use

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\items_data.xml");
var names = xDoc.Descendants("name")
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

-

```
 xDoc.Descendants("name")
    .Where(x => x.Value == "Name1")
    .First()
    .Parent.Add(new XElement("image", "path of the image"));
```

Comment: What's the using directive for it?